# How to use pandas groupby and shift together

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, apply

I'm sure I need to use some sort of apply functionality but I'm struggling to create one that accomplishes this. I have a dataframe with stock tickers and monthly returns. I need to calculate the forward 3 month returns. It's structured such that for every month, there will be 500 (made that number up) rows with all the stocks and the returns for that month. I've been trying something like this but it isn't working.

```
mr['Quarterly_Returns'] = mr.groupby('ticker')['monthly_returns'].apply(mr['monthly_returns']+mr['monthly_returns'].shift(-1)+mr['monthly_returns'].shift(-2))
```

And advice?

Comment: Do you need `mr['Quarterly_Returns'] = mr.groupby('ticker')['monthly_returns'].apply(lambda x: x+x.shift(-1)+x.shift(-2)) ` ?

Comment: I don't think so. That seems to give me a keyerror on the 'monthly_returns' column. I'll look into that though.

Comment: sorry, i edit comment.

Comment: Woah, yes that is it. I need to learn more about the apply functionality. Thank you so much. If you put it in as a solution I can mark as correct too!

Comment: Thank you, I add answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `lambda x` and in `apply` instead column names use `x`, because works only with column `monthly_returns`:

```
mr['Quarterly_Returns'] = mr.groupby('ticker')['monthly_returns']
                            .apply(lambda x: x+x.shift(-1)+x.shift(-2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider using the `rolling` functions.

`mr.groupby('ticker')['monthly_returns'].rolling(3).sum()`

A more complete example:

```
df=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('1/1/2016','12/31/2016',freq='M'),data={'ticker':x,'return':np.random.rand(12)}) for x in list('ABCD')])
df.groupby('ticker')['return'].rolling(3).sum().unstack('ticker')

ticker  A   B   C   D
2016-01-31  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2016-02-29  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2016-03-31  2.062552    1.508062    1.317836    1.051874
2016-04-30  1.727587    1.856383    1.308263    1.113360
2016-05-31  1.602858    2.112790    1.533763    1.039221
2016-06-30  1.716985    2.403718    1.850741    1.726469
2016-07-31  1.828597    1.809054    1.543079    1.569896
2016-08-31  2.003484    1.531877    1.376907    1.852235
2016-09-30  1.854642    1.319289    1.438446    0.946304
2016-10-31  1.308001    1.718987    1.764252    1.157938
2016-11-30  0.962660    2.255580    1.489076    0.493370
2016-12-31  0.949810    1.753511    1.321650    1.377429
```

Comment: I test it, but it return something else.

Comment: You can check it too - `mr = pd.DataFrame({'ticker':np.random.choice(['a','b','c','d'], 20), 
                   'monthly_returns': np.random.choice(1000, 20)})`

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, but it seems to me that it does exactly the right thing -- calculates the rolling sum for each ticker. The other solution concatenates all the results together, though I'm not sure I fully understand why.

Comment: Yes, I have same idea, so I test it with sample. I think it is same as `mr['Quarterly_Returns'] = mr.groupby('ticker')['monthly_returns']
                            .apply(lambda x: x+x.shift(1)+x.shift(2))`